# Labeling the last point of series

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that changes the last point in every series on my chart to the legend name. However, I do not want the last point of the first 4 series to change to the legend name. Does anyone have any suggestions for altering this code to skip the first 4 series and label the last point of every series?

```
For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection              'change this function so every series after series 4 changes ast point
    With mySrs

        nPts = .Points.Count
        mySrs.Points(nPts).ApplyDataLabels _
        Type:=xlDataLabelsShowValue, _
        AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False
        mySrs.Points(nPts).DataLabel.Text = mySrs.Name
        mySrs.Points(nPts).DataLabel.Orientation = 90
        mySrs.Points(nPts).DataLabel.Font.Bold = True

    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chart `Series` in Excel has a property called `PlotOrder` that tells you the order in which each series is plotted on the chart. You could check this property in your loop and only continue if it's `> 4`. For example:

```
For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection

    With mySrs

        If .PlotOrder > 4 Then
            nPts = .Points.Count
            ....
        End If

    End With

Next
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I had no idea about the PlotOrder property. Still learning...Thanks!